# Better way to write if-elif-elif-elif-else?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

How can I improve (reduce the writing) for this if-else block to run a method based on an option entered?
I've tried looking at SO and various other areas for solutions but didn't find something fit my problem.

```
def funcA(arg1, arg2):
    ...

def funcB(arg1):
    ...

def funcC():
    ...

def funcD():
    ...

def funcE():
    ...

if option == 1:
   funcA(arg1, arg2)
elif option == 2:
   funcB(arg1)
elif option == 3:
   funcC()
elif option == 4:
   funcD()
elif option == 5:
   funcE()
else:
   pass
```

Apologies if the code is not clear.

Comment: It seems fine as it is, IMHO.

Comment: But it seems that you already know the answer, you mention dictionary in the title

Comment: It's not just which function to call, but what arguments to pass to that function, that depends on the value of `option`. You can't just write `some_dict[option](...)`.

Comment: having differing amounts of parameters provided to functions will make it more complicated if you wrap the functions into dictonary values with options as keys. It can be done .. but you'll probably need args and kwargs and more if/elses. Just keep it as is. But change the names of functions/parameters to something more meaningful.

Comment: "I've tried looking at SO and various other areas for solutions but didn't find something fit my problem." Show us the specific things you found, and explain why they do not fit.

Comment: Yes Dani, you are right. I thought dictionary was a possible way but when I wanted to use arguments I didn't know how to. I will rephrase my question to make it clearer. Thank you.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I am trying to find the source, but can't. Sorry. I saw an implementation with a function map, with option as key and function as a value. But I wanted to pass arguments to some params as well instead of just calling it with empty brackets.

Comment: Use `functools.partial` to pre-bind the arguments to use.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a dictionary as a dispatch-table, and `namedtuples` to store a function & argument pairing.

```py
from collections import namedtuple

def funcA(arg1, arg2):
    print(f'I am funcA and you gave me {arg1} and {arg2}')
def funcB(arg):
    print(f'I am funcB and you gave me {arg}')
def funcC():
    print(f'I am funcC')
def funcD():
    print(f'I am funcD')
def funcE():
    print(f'I am funcE')

OptionPairing = namedtuple('OptionPairing', ['f', 'args'])

dispatch = {
  1: OptionPairing(funcA, [True, False]),
  2: OptionPairing(funcB, [True]),
  3: OptionPairing(funcC, []),
  4: OptionPairing(funcD, []),
  5: OptionPairing(funcE, [])
}

for i in range(1, 6):
    choice = dispatch[i]
    x = choice.f(*choice.args)
```

Running this, then, gives the following results:

```
I am funcA and you gave me True and False
I am funcB and you gave me True
I am funcC
I am funcC
I am funcE
```

---

If you want to specify yourself what arguments to pass to your function, simply this will suffice:

```py
dispatch = {
  1: funcA,
  2: funcB,
  3: funcC,
  4: funcD,
  5: funcE,
}
```

Then call your function like so:

```py
dispatch[option](args)
```

Making sure to pass the arguments `args`, as a list, since the number of arguments is variadic.

Comment: But the value of `args` almost certainly depends on the value of `option` as well.

Comment: Added this possibility to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a dictionary approach?

```py
funcs = {
    1: funcA,
    2: funcB,
    ...
}

func = funcs.get(option)
if func is None:
    return 

print(f"Running func: {func.__name__}")
func(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is common in python to do a switch-like struct with a dictionary as you said. However in your case the if/else looks ok I think since the following is a bit obfuscated:

```
option = 2

def funcA(arg1, arg2):
    print("A")

def funcB(arg1):
    print("B")

def funcC():
    print("C")

def funcD():
    print("D")

def funcE():
    print("E")

func, args = {
    1: (funcA, ("arg1", "arg2")),
    2: (funcB, ("arg1",)),
    3: (funcC, ()),
    4: (funcD, ()),
    5: (funcE, ()),
}.get(option, (None, (),))

if func:
    func(*args)
```

It really depends on how many functions and args you have but I would suggest for a few functions to stick to if/else

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary of the functions and their args :

```
actions = {
  1: [ func1 , [arg1,arg2] ]
  2: [ func2 , [arg1] ]
  3: [ func3 , []]
  4: [ func4 , []]
  5: [ func5 , []]
}

def doAction( actions , option ):
    if option in actions:
        func, args = actions[option]
        func(*args)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a helper function fo imitate a switch/case statement and avoid the ugly repetitions (and corresponding maintenance hassles):

```
def switch(value): yield lambda *match: value in match
```

example usage:

```
for case in switch(option):
    if   case(1): funcA(arg1, arg2)
    elif case(2): funcB(arg1)
    elif case(3): funcC()
    elif case(4): funcD()
    elif case(5): funcE()
```